# How to differenciated between ERC20 transactions and normal transaqctions when getting raw transactions using web3

Tags: etherscan, web3.py

When looking at etherscan transactions are divided as normal transactions or ERC20 transactions. When using web3 and getting the transaction, correct me if Im not wrong, but all of them are bundled together. How can I differenciate between then?
(Instead of using the coins ABI I use the first inputs first 4 bytes to decodethem)

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan and other block explorers rely on the events that contract emit to categorise transactions as token transfers like ERC20/721/1155.

In your case, you can do the same. Check the `logs` of transactions (given you have the txn hash) for the `event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value)` event and double check by calling the view function like `symbol` or `decimals` on the `to` address of transaction.